# Excel VLOOKUP using String to look for data in a File. Goes too slow

Tags: excel, while-loop, concatenation, vlookup, vba

This is the best I can get. Incase anyone searches and needs the best answer for this type of data pull.  I had to break it down into sections; these work computers just can't handle this type of load.  Max data pull is around 800 lines and takes around a minute to pull all the formula(s) and data. Thanks to the people below with thier help.

```
Sub Update()

Dim ScreenUpdateState As Boolean
Dim StatusBarShow As Boolean
Dim CalcState As Long
Dim EventState As Boolean

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim location_string As String
Dim count As Integer

'Save the current state of Excel settings
ScreenUpdateState = Application.ScreenUpdating
StatusBarShow = Application.DisplayStatusBar
CalcState = Application.Calculation
EventState = Application.EnableEvents

'Change Excel to faster procedure settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("%")
location_string = Sheets("Driver(s)").Cells(5, "G").Text

For count = 7 To 139
Cells(count, "F").Formula = "=IFERROR((VLOOKUP($C" & count    & ",'S:\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxxxxx\[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xlsx]" + location_string + "'!$A:$K,11,FALSE)),"" - "")"
Next count

'Restore Excel settings to original state
Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdateState
Application.DisplayStatusBar = StatusBarShow
Application.Calculation = CalcState
Application.EnableEvents = EventState

MsgBox ("Update Complete")
End Sub
```

Good luck!

- Ross

***Orignal thread:***

> Ok I have this now and it works. It however is to slow to be used as
>   this one code only runs maybe 1/16th of the required calculations and
>   takes a few minutes to complete. Anyone know a way to speed up the
>   process?
>
> ```
> Sub Test()
> Dim ws As Worksheet
> Dim location_string As String
> Dim count As Integer
>
> Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("%")
> location_string = ws.Cells(2, "E").Text
>
> count = 7
>
> While count < 138
> Cells(count, "F").Formula = "=IFERROR((VLOOKUP($C" & count & ",
> 'S:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\[xxxxxx.xlsx]" + location_string + "'!$A:$K,11,FALSE)),"" - "")"
> count = count + 1
> Wend
>
> MsgBox ("Done")
> End Sub
> ```
>
> Below is the original post:
>
> I have a list of values on another sheet that will create part of the
>   string I need:
>
> ```
> =CONCATENATE ((INDEX('Driver(s)'!$B$1:$B$48,'Driver(s)'!$G$3,1)),"Epic")
> ```
>
> this will set a cell to = 'O614Epic
>
> now trying to add a Vlookup to pull from:
>
> ```
> S:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx\xx\xx\xx\[Random File Name.xlsx]0614Epic'!$A:$K
> ```
>
> Based on the drop down box, the ####Epic file will change to the
>   correct value as a string at the moment but can not get Vlookup to
>   pull from the correct workbook.  I also need this to open non-opened
>   workbooks.  Too much data to import into the Excel workbook itself.
>
> Thanks.
>
> - Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no getting around using VLOOKUP, skip to the Bonus Info.  Instead of having VLOOKUP formulas recalculating with every change and slowing down your spreadsheet, you can use VBA to find and put the value in the cell instead of a formula.  I did my best to tailor it to what you provided.  Please let me know if you have questions on any parts.

```
Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Application.Proper(Sht.Name) = Application.Proper(WorksheetName) Then
        WorksheetExists = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next Sht

End Function

Sub RossQuestion()
    Dim wbdata As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim location_string As String
    Dim strcheck As String
    Dim count As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("%")
location_string = ws.Cells(2, "E").Text
count = 7

While count < 138
    Set wbdata = Workbooks.Open("S:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx.xlsx", , True)
    If WorksheetExists(location_string) Then
        Set Cell = wbdata.Sheets(location_string).Columns("A").Find(ws.Range("$C$" & count).Value, _
        wbdata.Sheets(location_string).Range("A1"), xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False)
        strcheck = Cell.Offset(0, 10).Value
        If Len(Trim(strcheck)) <> 0 Then
            ws.Cells(count, "F").Value = Cell.Offset(0, 10).Value
        Else
            ws.Cells(count, "F").Value = " - "
        End If
    Else
        ws.Cells(count, "F").Value = " - "
    End If
    count = count + 1
    wbdata.Close False
Wend

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

***Bonus Info:***

If you're not wrapping your code in something like this, consider using this for all future VBA.  The 1st tip in [this link](http://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/) details these actions.

```
Dim ScreenUpdateState As Boolean
Dim StatusBarShow As Boolean
Dim CalcState As Long
Dim EventState As Boolean

'Save the current state of Excel settings
ScreenUpdateState = Application.ScreenUpdating
StatusBarShow = Application.DisplayStatusBar
CalcState = Application.Calculation
EventState = Application.EnableEvents

'Change Excel to faster procedure settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'<<<YOUR CODE HERE>>>

'Restore Excel settings to original state
Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdateState
Application.DisplayStatusBar = StatusBarShow
Application.Calculation = CalcState
Application.EnableEvents = EventState
```

***Original Answer:***

While you can reference data from other workbooks (even non-opened), your path in VLOOKUP's table_array argument has to be completely typed in.

So while VLOOKUP accepts...

```
=VLOOKUP('Driver(s)'!$G$3, 'S:\xxxxx\FileName.xlsx'!$A:$K, 3, FALSE)
```

it won't accept any calculations or concatenations in the table_array such as...

```
=VLOOKUP('Driver(s)'!$G$3, 'S:\xxxxx\ & O614Epic & .xlsx'!$A:$K, 3, FALSE)
=VLOOKUP('Driver(s)'!$G$3, 'S:\xxxxx\ & INDIRECT(B1) & Epic.xlsx'!$A:$K, 3, FALSE)
```

Anything other than the complete path string is considered too volatile.  Same goes for MATCH INDEX.  Unfortunately VLOOKUP isn't as dynamic as you'd like and ####Epic needs to be typed as O614Epic by you and not coming from another cell.

There's always VBA.  Everything's possible with VBA.

Comment: Added some VBA and it works. Just too slow. Ideas? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the speed up section.  As for the other code it makes it worse, opening the file for every pull.  Unfortunatly I think I'll just have to break up the large file into smaller segments and try that.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the loop and try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim location_string As String
    Dim myformula As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("%")
    location_string = ws.Cells(2, "E").Value '~~> I'd suggest you use Value

    myformula = "=IFERROR((VLOOKUP($C7,'S:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\[xxxxxx.xlsx]" & _
        location_string & "'!$A:$K,11,FALSE)),"" - "")"

    Range("F7:F138").Formula = myformula
    Msgbox "Done"

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

This takes 5 sec in my machine but it will differ specially if the target file is in a network server. HTH.

Comment: Getting an error on the Range.Forumla = myformula line. Will tweek with it some in a bit see what I can come up with. Thanks for the help.